# Decomposition of $\text{GL}^+(2,\mathbb{Q})$ into $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z})-$left cosets

Tags: matrices, group-theory, matrix-decomposition

Consider the following group: $$\text{GL}^+(2,\mathbb{Q})=\{M\in\text{GL}(2,\mathbb{Q}):\det M>0\}$$
I'm trying to prove the following fact:
$$\text{GL}^+(2,\mathbb{Q})=\bigsqcup_{\substack{x,z\in\mathbb{Q}\ \cap\ (0,+\infty)\\y\in\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}}}\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z})\begin{pmatrix}x&y\\0&z\end{pmatrix}$$

My only problem is to prove that the union in the RHS is a disjoint union. This is my attempt: given $x_1,x_2,z_1,z_2\in\mathbb{Q}\cap(0,+\infty)$ and $y_1,y_2\in\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z},$ suppose that
$$\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z})\begin{pmatrix}
  x_1&y_1\\
  0&z_1
 \end{pmatrix}=\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z})\begin{pmatrix}
  x_2&y_2\\
  0&z_2
 \end{pmatrix}$$
Considering the determinant, I immediately get $x_1z_1=x_2z_2.$ I can rewrite the preceding relation in the following way:
$$
\frac{1}{x_1z_1}\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z})\begin{pmatrix}
  x_1&y_1\\
  0&z_1
 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
  z_2&-y_2\\
  0&x_2
 \end{pmatrix}=\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$$

$$\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z})\begin{pmatrix}
  \displaystyle\frac{z_2}{z_1}&\displaystyle-\frac{y_2}{z_1}+\frac{y_1}{z_2}\\[10pt]
  0&\displaystyle\frac{x_2}{x_1}
 \end{pmatrix}=\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$$
$$\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z})\cdot M=\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$$

From this I should get that $M\in\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$ and in particular, using the hypothesis $x_1,x_2,z_1,z_2>0,$ that $z_1=z_2,x_1=x_2,$ hence
$$M=\begin{pmatrix}
  \displaystyle 1 &\displaystyle-\frac{y_2+y_1}{z_1}\\[10pt]
  0&\displaystyle1
 \end{pmatrix}\in\Gamma(1)$$

Is it everything right? I don't know how to prove that $y_2-y_1$ is an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a mistake in your question, it is $y\in \Bbb{Q/zZ}$ not $y\in \Bbb{Q/Z}$.

You got that $$\pmatrix{x_1&y_1\\0&z_1}=\pmatrix{1&n\\0&1} \pmatrix{x_2&y_2\\0&z_2}$$
so that $x_1=x_2,z_1=z_2$ and $y_1 = y_2+nz_2$ ie. $\pmatrix{x_1&y_1+z_1\Bbb{Z}\\0&z_1}=\pmatrix{x_2&y_2+z_2\Bbb{Z}\\0&z_2}$ as wanted.

It remains to prove that every $\pmatrix{u&v\\w&z}\in GL_2(\Bbb{Q})^+$ matrix is in one of the cosets. If $uw\ne 0$, write that $(u,w)=r (d,-c)$ for some coprime integers, take $a,b$ such that $ad-bc=1$ then look at $\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}\pmatrix{u&v\\w&z}$. For the case $w=0$ there is nothing to do, for the case $u=0$ use $\pmatrix{0&1\\-1&0}$.

Comment: Ok thanks, then I think there is a mistake in the text of the exercise I was trying to solve. I didn't have problems on proving that each matrix in $\text{GL}^+(2,\mathbb{Q})$ is in one of the cosets, my solution is exactly yours. Only one question: what do you mean with the symbol ℤ? In your solution I have $y_1-y_2\in z_1\mathbb{Z}$ but $z_1$ depends on the matrices I have taken. Is there a unique set in which I can choose $b$ to get a representative of each coset?

Comment: $y\in [0,z)$ if you prefer. $z\Bbb{Z}$ is a subgroup of $\Bbb{Q}$ and $\Bbb{Q}/z\Bbb{Z}$ is a quotient group similar to $\Bbb{Q/Z}$.

Comment: I mean, is there a unique $z$ and a unique subgroup in which I can choose each representative? It seems not...

Comment: I don't see what you mean. Simply set $y=tz$ with $t\in \Bbb{Q/Z}$.

Comment: I mean, can you list a set of representatives of the cosets? I can choose $x$ and $z$ on all the positive rational numbers, but is there a set in which I can choose $y$ such that each element gives a different representative? I'm sorry, I don't know if I'm missing something or if I didn't explain well my question...

Comment: $y\in [0,z)$ ${}{}{}$

Comment: Ok, maybe I have understood what you mean: I fix $x,z$ and for each choice of these elements $y$ determines a representative running over $\mathbb{Q}/z\mathbb{Z},$ right?